# C++11: template function call of a template method doesn't compile?

Tags: c++, c++11, function-templates

The following program, if compiled as shown, outputs `size: 1  align: 1`.

However, trying to make the same method-template call from a templatized function doesn't work.

If I change `#if 0` to `#if 1` g++ 9.2.1 gives me error `expected primary-expression before 'char'`.  clang++ gives a more helpful-sounding `error: use 'template' keyword to treat 'log' as a dependent template name` but I'm not sure where it wants template to occur.

So what gives?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



class Foo {

public:
  Foo() {};
  ~Foo() {};
  void log( int iSizeItem, int iAlignItem ) {
    cout << "size: " << iSizeItem << "  align: " << iAlignItem << endl;
  }
  
  template<class T> void log() {
    log( sizeof( T ), alignof( T ) );
  }
};


#if 0
template<class T> void Test( T& t ) {
  t.log<char>();
}
#endif


int main( int nArg, char* apszArg[] ) {
  Foo foo;
  foo.log<char>();

  //Test( foo );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: My question is apparently also answered under a omnibus question of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords ... however I find that question overly broad.  If anything it should be broken into pieces, like mine, that are easier to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that `log` is a function template, like this:

```
template<class T> void Test( T& t ) {
  t.template log<char>();
}
```

Otherwise the compiler doesn't know if `log` is a member of `T`, and `<` is actually `operator<`.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/uBfz4H).

Comment: Works perfectly in g++ 9.2.1 and clang++ 9.0.1.  No idea why you got down-voted for it!  I've programmed C++ since 1992 and not seen that syntax before...